# left join not working or maybe I don't know how to use it

Tags: sql

I'm trying to generate a query with left join. The idea is that I can get:

```
JOBA,SCRIPTA
JOBA,SCRIPTC
```

**Because I need only rows that have same columnA (job), with different columnB (bat).**

I'm trying with left join but it is not working. Could you help me why my sql sentence is wrong?

```
create table definition
(
   job varchar(256),
   bat varchar(256)
);

INSERT INTO definition (job,bat)
VALUES
   ('JOBA','SCRIPTA'),
   ('JOBA','SCRIPTA'),
   ('JOBB','SCRIPTB'),
   ('JOBA','SCRIPTC'),
   ('JOBB','SCRIPTB');
```

```
with duplicates as 
(
select distinct a.job,a.bat from definition a where job in (
    SELECT job
      FROM definition
      GROUP BY job
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) order by job desc
),
  duplicatetwofields as 
(
SELECT job, bat
     FROM definition
  GROUP BY job, bat
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 order by job desc
) 
select a.job,a.bat from duplicates a left join  duplicatetwofields b
on (a.job=b.job)
  --and a.bat=b.bat) 
where a.bat is null or a.job is null;
```

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Explain the logic you want to implement.  "Not working" doesn't convey much information, and even less to people who don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Simplify, [mcve].

Comment: Ok, I'm going to modify the main question

Comment: Yes, please modify the main question.  You need to describe more of what you are trying to accomplish.  If you just want the output printed at the top of your original question, a query like `select distinct on (bat) job, bat from definition where job = 'JOBA';` would do it (but I'm sure that's not what you want).  Also, in your final query, you don't reference `duplicates` -- is that intentional?  If so, then you may as well remove it to avoid confusion

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've edited main question. I hope that the question could be understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUPBY` with `COUNT()` will get you there, but the code in your original question is not exactly what you want:

```
SELECT job
FROM definition
GROUP BY job
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

You're putting `job` values into groups and then pulling the value if the group count is greater than one. Both `JOBA` and `JOBB` exist more than once, so every `job` group has more than one member. This means `JOBA` and `JOBB` both get returned. What you want is something like this:

```
SELECT job
FROM definition
GROUP BY job
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(bat)) > 1
```

This puts the `job`s into groups, but only returns them if there is more than one distinct `bat` for every `job`. This query only returns `JOBA` because `JOBA` is the only group that has more than 1 distinct `bat` value.

You also don't need to eliminate duplicates with a second CTE. Simply use a distinct on the final query to get unique results. Something like this should work given the parameters of the question (I used a subquery, it's fine to use a CTE if you prefer):

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.*
FROM definition d
JOIN
(
    SELECT job
    FROM definition
    GROUP BY job
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(bat)) > 1
) x
ON d.job = x.job
```

[DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e1386f7e3f9ce807b68781e4568b2234)

EDIT: [DbFiddle with `ISNULL()` to handle null values](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=daf5e949a6cecf6b1d4be671690b037b).

Comment: Fantastic answer, I've noted a problem with your query, if there is null values don't get rows with null values. See it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d28db0c543e01aa7653dc53b3709fa97

Comment: @absolute333 that's because `NULL` is not a value, it's a representation of "no value." When you have values of, say, `BAT123` and `NULL`, SQL Server (and likely other RDBMS) consider that distinct count to be 1.. you have one value that is `BAT123`, and then you have "nothing." So, one distinct value. Use `ISNULL` or a similar function inside the `COUNT(DISTINCT())` to work with nulls.

Comment: Thanks!. Last question. Do you know why my main query not works. I thing have good logic but not works I mean auxiliary table with duplicates by column job. Other auxiliary table with duplicates by the two columns (job and bat). Then I use left join explicit to get the output expected.

Comment: @absolute333 main query? Meaning the original query in your question?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my english. Origial query in my question

Comment: @absolute333 the main issue is in the `duplicates` CTE. You need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT(ISNULL(bat, '')))` to only get jobs with more than one bat. `duplicates` actually contains all the logic you need for your query with that one change. `duplicatetwofields` is not necessary. The final query is basically a `SELECT`. See [this DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef759783e444173de4f8a6e124bf36d5).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with EXISTS:

```
select distinct d.*
from definition d
where exists (
  select 1 from definition
  where job = d.job and bat <> d.bat
)
```

Or:

```
select distinct *
from definition
where job in (
  select job
  from definition
  group by job
  having count(distinct bat) > 1
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fd80dd14ff3222b8048cf87828ae8d0f).
Results:

```
> job  | bat    
> :--- | :------
> JOBA | SCRIPTA
> JOBA | SCRIPTC
```